# Задержка на каждый 5-ый MouseMove

Tags: c#, winforms

Программа состоит в том, что кнопка "убегает" от курсора (прописано в MouseMove кнопки).

Проблема в том, что делает она это слишком быстро и не успеваешь "поймать" её и нажать.

Нужно, чтобы на каждое пятое наведение мыши тормозилось перемещение кнопки на 1 секунду.

Задержка установлена через Delay. Вопрос в том, через что можно сделать задержку не на КАЖДОЕ наведение, а на КАЖДОЕ ПЯТОЕ. В гугле подобного не нашла. Хотя бы в каком направлении искать?

while (Location.X < 300 && Location.Y < 150)

await Task.Delay(1000);

P.S. Это дубль вопроса, т.к. из-за участника aepot его опустили и дальше так и не пошло. Я новичок, поэтому прошу не гнобить с первых же строк. Если нужно что-то уточнить - я напишу. Только напишите, что нужно. Не весь же код сюда пихать.

Comment: Задача прям под ReactiveExtensions :)

Comment: Спасибо, принял к сведению.

Comment: Андрей NOP, я ещё слишком неграмотная для Rx. :) Хотя по описанию очень полезная штука.    Просто пишу код по прочитанной теме и по ходу добавляю что-то своё. Но не всегда (в большинстве случаев ^^") знаний реализовать это что-то не хватает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно Вам нужно добавить переменную для отсчёта наведений:

```
int i = 0;

// ...

if(i >= 5)
{
    i = 0;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
else
{
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Логику поняла. Добавила в if и else изменение Location кнопки и пошло почти как надо. Буду допиливать. )